# variables vs long algorithms

Tags: c++, performance

what are the differences between using these two algorithms. I've always wondered how I should be optimising things.How do they differ memory and speed wise? Is one better than the other? Aside from code clarity I mean.

this is the first version I had:

```
bool Intersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 vectorBetween = (centre - boundingSphere.centre);

    // works out the distance between the sphere centre's using pythag
    float distance = sqrt(
                         pow(vectorBetween.x, 2) 
                       + pow(vectorBetween.y, 2) 
                       + pow(vectorBetween.z, 2));

    // if two radius's add to more than the distance between the centres
    return (radius + boundingSphere.radius > distance);
}
```

This method is the same, but it doesn't hold any values in variables, it just uses one long calculation

```
bool Intersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
    return (radius + boundingSphere.radius >
            (sqrt(pow((centre - boundingSphere.centre).x, 2) +
                  pow((centre - boundingSphere.centre).y, 2) +
                  pow((centre - boundingSphere.centre).z, 2))));
}
```

Comment: the second one requires more calculations, while the first has a float and a struct associated with it...

Comment: Have you tested the performance of both? If not, do this first, and then ask if you need help interpreting the results.

Comment: you should probably be profiling instead. All compilers are able to opimize common sub expressions.

Comment: Well memory is cleared once call to first version gets over . So memory wise they would be the same . Speed :: Well if compiler does optimize "(centre - boundingSphere.centre)" then version 2 should be faster else version 1

Comment: There's no need to use `pow(x,2)` where `x * x` will suffice by the way: save yourself a function call :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two algorithms will, under proper optimization options, compile down to exactly the same code. Since the first is far more readable, it is undoubtedly the better of the two.

The correct way to optimize this code is not to get rid of the variables (the compiler can do that for you), but to get rid of the sqrt operation: just compare squared distances.

Comment: Also, you may well find that `x*x` is faster than `pow(x,2)`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour even after the compiler deals with it?

Comment: so sebastian, you're saying that it would be better to square the sum of radius and boundingSphere.radius and compare that rather than sqrt the distance variable. Why is one better than the other? Thanks.

Comment: @Sir: because if `sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1) > sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2)` then `(x1*x1 + y1*y1) > (x2*x2 + y2*y2)`. `sqrt` is monotonic.

Comment: @Sir: The compiler could only optimize `pow(x,2)` to `x*x` if it could be sure that you had not linked in another function named `pow`.

Comment: OK, I get it. The only thing I don't get is that I would be adding an extra square function essentially to replace the square root function. Why is squaring something better than square rooting something?

Comment: @SirYakalot: as long as you use multiplication rather than `pow`, squaring is almost certainly faster than taking the square root.

Comment: because it's a function call or because it's more complicated to calculate?

Comment: Because it's far more complicated to calculate. Calculating square root essentially comes down to making an educated guess what the square root could be, squaring it to check, then refining that guess, until you're satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which one is easier to maintain?

I think your first version is easier, since it breaks out the parts and makes the `vectorBetween` obvious, as you reuse that a couple of times.

Now, as to which one is faster... a smart compiler will probably figure out how to make both the same speed. Don't worry too much about that until you need to. We are talking about O(1) differences here anyways, so if you *do* do this in a tight loop, just *test* both versions. Then you will know which one is faster!

Answer (score 0):

Do whichever is clearest for you.  If there are performance problems,
try the other.  Without more exact information concerning the type of
`D3DXVECTOR3` and the return value of the `operator-` you're using and
any number of other factors, it's impossible to even make a guess as to
which is faster.  And until you know that this code is critical, it
doesn't really matter.

Comment: D3DXVECTOR3 is a struct with three floats, the operator is a minus sign. It is critical.

Comment: The operator is overloaded.  So how it is implemented will impact on your performance.  Again, the only way to know which has the better performance is to benchmark: if `operator-` is inline, the compiler might actually be able to optimize better with the three calls to it; if it isn't, and the compiler can't see the source code, calling it once will probably be optimal (but making it `inline` might have a higher payoff than modifying this code).

Answer (score 0):

The best you can hope for with the second variant is that the compiler will optimize it to do exactly the same as the first rather than computing the difference vector three times. In either case, the machine will need to store the intermediate results somewhere; it doesn't really matter whether that intermediate storage is a named C++ variable or an anonymous machine language pointer.

And of course this is premature micro-optimization and completely irrelevant compared to the better readability of the first variant.